# Wysiwyg display

Tags: 7, theming, wysiwyg

Please, any one can help,
Why the Wysiwyg editor is displaying for some templates and is hiding (disabling) for some others one.
I tried to use it with Kanji 7.x-2.0 and Bartik 7.10 and seven 7.10, it works very well but with other template like business connection template n

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug/shortcomming of the theme. Think about posting an issue to its queue.